# How do I resolve a jQuery fading animation conflict in my navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am currently working on a company website on Wordpress that has a navigation menu that would seamlessly load the link's content after fade in through the jQuery `load()` function. Like so:

```
$("#header .menu a, #header .logo, nav.menu_mobile a:not('.close')").bind('click',function () {

var href = $(this).attr("href");
var title = $(this).attr("title");

history.pushState(null, title, href);

$("#page").fadeOut(500, function() {
    $("#page").delay(500).empty();
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
    $("#header").removeClass("scrolled");
});

$('#page').load(href + " .content", function() {
    $('#page').fadeIn(500, function(){

        if ( $("#main").has(".posts") ) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                masonrygrid();
            }, 1000);
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            $("body").getNiceScroll().resize();
        }, 500);

    });
});

return false;
});
```

Currently, I'm having problems executing the "Work" page, which is basically a portfolio page.

There should be a modal box that would fade in when the posts are clicked and all of the images from the posts would be shown on the modal box.

When the "Work" page is accessed through the address bar, the function (shown below) would work fine. However, when the page is accessed through the navigation menu, though, the function doesn't work.

```
$(".page-id-44 .post .meta").click(function() {
    $("#gallery").fadeIn();
    return false;
});

$("#gallery .close").click(function() {
    $("#gallery").fadeOut();
    return false;
});
```

Demo: [trivecs.com](http://trivecs.com) (still under construction, though)

Comment: Can you post error you are getting in console ?

Comment: @shyammakwana.me, see the solution below, it's the WP/jQuery No Conflict mode.

Comment: @Difster I know, my answer is saying the same.

Comment: Tried the suggestions so far, the "Work" page problem is still happening, especially when the "Work" link is accessed through the navigation menu.

Comment: unrelated but I love your design <3. Look so cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, by default `$` won't work in WordPress as it is. 
Because, jQuery supplied with WordPress is in noConflict mode to avoid issues with other libraries that may use the $ as their object reference.

So wrap your all jquery code inside this.

```
(function($){
    // your code here
})(jQuery)
```

### Update:

Above code will work if it's jQuery's issue ($ is not a function). If there's other issue, post error in question from console.

### Update2:

I found the issue on your website: 
Change code for work page like below.

It's event delegation. When page loads you don't have those class in your DOM, so when you navigate via navigation then you are adding those dynamically. So event delegation is for that dynamic classes in `document`.  [See this link](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on('click', ".page-id-44 .post .meta", function() {
    $("#gallery").fadeIn();
    return false;
});

$(document).on('click', "#gallery .close", function() {
    $("#gallery").fadeOut();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What if I need to get the href of `.page-id-44 .post .meta` as a `var`, so this can be referenced as a `this`?

Answer (score 2):

With Wordpress, you just use `jQuery(document).ready(function($){    });`

And then everything inside of that, you can use the $ like you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    // $ Works! You can test it with next line if you like
    // console.log($);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery of all " $ ".

```js
jQuery("#header .menu a, #header .logo, nav.menu_mobile a:not('.close')").bind('click',function () {

var href = jQuery(this).attr("href");
var title = jQuery(this).attr("title");

history.pushState(null, title, href);

jQuery("#page").fadeOut(500, function() {
    jQuery("#page").delay(500).empty();
    jQuery(window).scrollTop(0);
    jQuery("#header").removeClass("scrolled");
});

jQuery('#page').load(href + " .content", function() {
    jQuery('#page').fadeIn(500, function(){

        if ( jQuery("#main").has(".posts") ) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                masonrygrid();
            }, 1000);
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery("body").getNiceScroll().resize();
        }, 500);

    });
});

return false;
});
```